PostgreSQL поиск по массиву объектов в JSON
Как сделать правильный SQL запрос для поиска по JSON полю
Пример таблицы table1



id
sections




1
[{"key":"xxx", "name":"Name One"},{"key":"yyy", "name":"Name Two"}]


2
[{"key":"zzz", "name":"Name Tre"},{"key":"xxx", "name":"Name One"}]


3
[{"key":"aaa", "name":"Name For"},{"key":"zzz", "name":"Name Tre"}]



Необходимо сделать запрос типа
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE sections->key IN('xxx','zzz')

Соответственно должно вернуть 1,2,3
Помимо этого было бы плюсом, как организовать корректный relation в Laravel по этому JSON полю.

Если просто поиск, по 1 значению key, то вот такой запрос:
SELECT * FROM "table1" WHERE sections@>'[{"key":"xxx"}]'::jsonb
Но как его модифицировать пока не понимаю

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, (json_array_elements(sections))->>'key' value
  FROM test
  )
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM cte
WHERE value IN ('xxx', 'zzz');

fiddle

Спасибо, но для поля с типом jsonb данная функция не работает

Для JSONB надо использовать функцию jsonb_array_elements

@Jeid Ну вы же сами явно указали тип поля: для поиска по JSON полю... вот я и написал код для этого типа.

Ну или такой вариант этого запроса:
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM (SELECT id,jsonb_array_elements(sections)->>'key' AS key
FROM table1) as t1 WHERE key IN('xxx', 'zzz')

@Jeid Ну это просто отказываемся от CTE и превращаем структурированный запрос в кашу. Ни на что другое такое изменение формы не повлияет.

Придумал вот такой вариант:
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE  sections @? '$[*].key ? (@ == "xxx" || @ == "zzz")';

UPD: и вот такой вариант
SELECT id FROM table1, jsonb_array_elements(sections) AS sec WHERE sec->>'key' IN('xxx', 'zzz');

